# Parse buffer image to base64 on React Native

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, buffer

I am trying to show an image gotten from a server in a React Native app. What I am getting in the response look like this:

[image]

I tried to build a Buffer object using [buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer) and then parse to base64

```
const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(res.data)) // This res.data is the whole object, including the type "Buffer" and the data array
const imageBase64 = imageBuffer.toString('base64')
setImage(imageBase64)
```

This returns a base64 image but it doesn't show using the React Native Image component

```
<Image source={{ uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${image}` }} />
```

I didn't found how to handle images with this structure (a buffer as a numbers array) on React Native. I was thinking that maybe it is a way to do this without the library mentioned or without parse the buffer to a base64 but I don't know.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont see any width and height provided to your image, this is the first common issue I faced and wasted my whole day, after providing the width and height, even if the image is not shown see the below solution

I have used this function to convert BufferArray into Base64

source [link](https://gist.github.com/Deliaz/e89e9a014fea1ec47657d1aac3baa83c)

```
  arrayBufferToBase64 = buffer => {
    let binary = '';
    let bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    let len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return window.btoa(binary);
  };
```

I have utilized the above function like this

```
              <Image
                style={{
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                  resizeMode: 'cover',
                  backgroundColor: 'red',
                }}
                source={{
                  uri:
                    'data:image/jpeg;base64,' +
                    this.arrayBufferToBase64(data.data), //data.data in your case
                }}
              />
```

Comment: I thought it was something with how I was parsing the image but this is exactly what I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, do we have to install Uint8Array as a plugin?

Comment: No, its inbuilt method